# MATLAB App Designer hold on/off throwing warnings

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I'm beginner and trying to use `polarplot` and `hold on/off` in MATLAB App Designer. Now to use this in app designer, we need to create the polar axes by calling the `polaraxes` function in the app designer panel container.

I tried this which is working fine without any error:

```
pax = polaraxes(app.Panel);
polarplot(pax,th1,r1,'red')
hold(app.UIFigure.CurrentAxes,'on');          % warning
polarplot(pax,th2,r2,'green')
hold(app.UIFigure.CurrentAxes,'off');         % warning
```

But due to app coding alerts, I'm getting the warning "Specify a UIAxes handle as first argument" for the hold line. How do I resolve this warning ? Is this the correct way to use `hold on/off` for the panel container?

Answer (score 1):

A similar question was answered over at [MATLAB Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/357588-app-designer-keeps-telling-me-to-specify-a-uiaxes-handle-as-first-argument-when-the-first-argument#answer_282801).

This is just a warning from the code analyzer, and not necessarily something specifically wrong with your code. You get this warning because when using App Designer it expects that you're using a `UIAxes` rather than a standard `Axes` object. You really can just ignore this warning.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used appdesigner much, but I suspect its because the CurrentAxes variable is empty that you get a warning, so you could try to specify the axes to hold:

```
pax = polaraxes(app.Panel);
polarplot(pax,th,r1,'red')
hold(pax,'on');          
polarplot(pax,r2,'green')
hold(pax,'off');
```

Or this might work (untested, and not recommended if it does, its always advisable to pass the actual axes handle that you want to hold rather than the one Matlab thinks is active)

```
pax = polaraxes(app.Panel);
polarplot(pax,th,r1,'red')
drawnow()
hold(app.UIFigure.CurrentAxes,'on');          % warning
polarplot(pax,r2,'green')
hold(app.UIFigure.CurrentAxes,'off');         % warning
```

Comment: I tried and in both the cases, the same warning still exist.

Comment: can you update your question to include the actual warning message and a minimum amount of code to re-create it